# What kind of execution can I expect for a typical NYSE stock trade by a broker?

Tags: stocks

If I call my broker to sell a stock at say 10am in the morning and assuming that he does whatever he has to do to sell it immediately, can I assume that it will be sold more or less immediately (within 15 minutes) at the market price?

Comment: In today's era of technology, 15 minutes is far more time than needed to execute a trade at market price.

Comment: Do you not have online access to enter such an order yourself? A market order typically fills in under a second.

Answer (score 1):

On a liquid stock a market order fills the time it hits the exchange. Fraction of seconds. The only delay will be the time taken by your broker to enter the order.

On illiquid stock, this can take time. But there are people waiting for such market orders and make tons of money by putting a favourable ask or bid.

Comment: On the NYSE if the order is for more than 1099 shares, and the specialist is busy talking to someone, it could take a few minutes...

Comment: It would have to be extremely illiquid, where the total size on the bid side at all prices are less than the order size, to take more than a few seconds to fill a market order. If there isn't enough size at the current bid, the market order will fill at each bid until the entire order size is sold. He'd just get a really awful average price.